# Is there a clever way to get rid of these loops using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, operations-research, value-iteration

I'm reaching the maximum recursion depth and I've been trying to use `np.tensordot()` I couldn't really get an insight into how to use it in this case.

```py
def stopping_condtion(a,V,V_old,eps):
    return  np.max(la.norm(V - V_old)) < ((1 - a) * eps)  / a

def value_iteration(net_profit, a, P,V,k = 0):
    eps = 0.1
    m = len(net_profit)
    n = len(V)

    A = np.zeros((n,m))

    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,m):
            A[i,j] = net_profit[j,i] + a * np.sum(P[j,:,i]) * V[j] 
            
    V_new = np.max(A,axis = 1)

    if stopping_condtion(a,V_new,V,eps):
        print(f'a* =  {np.argmax(A,axis = 1)} with alpha = {a} after n = {k} iterations ')
        return np.argmax(A,axis = 1)
    
    return value_iteration(net_profit, a, P,V_new,k+1)
```

These are the inputs

```py
profit = np.array([900, 800 , 600 , 400, 100])
cost   = np.array([0  , 80  , 800])

net_profit = (np.tile(profit,(3,1)).transpose() - cost).transpose()
alpha  = np.array([0.3, 0.6 , 0.9])


P  = np.array([ [[0.6, 0.4  , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [0  , 0.5  , 0.3 , 0.2, 0  ],
                 [0  , 0    , 0.4 , 0.3, 0.3],
                 [0  , 0    , 0   , 0.5, 0.5],
                 [0  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 1  ]],
               
                [[0.8, 0.2  , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [0  , 0.8  , 0.2 , 0  , 0  ],
                 [0  , 0.2  , 0.6 , 0.2, 0  ],
                 [0  , 0    , 0.3 , 0.6, 0.1],
                 [0  , 0    , 0   , 0.5, 0.5]],
               
                [[1  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [1  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [1  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [1  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
                 [1  , 0    , 0   , 0  , 0  ]] ])

V = np.zeros(len(P[0,0]))
value_iteration(net_profit,alpha[0],P,V)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the loop and  only use the Numpy operations for efficiency sake.

Comment: what is ```a```, ```V```, ```k``` ?

Comment: @kevin It's in the snippet underneath now. Thanks for the quick repsonse!

Comment: You should probably turn the tail recursion into a loop. There's no reason to use recursion here at all

Comment: @MadPhysicist Even if I do that it says that I reach the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: You can't reach maximum recursion depth if you don't recurse

Comment: I see I messed up the stopping condition. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a transposition and broadcasting like the following (untested) code.

```py
A = net_profit.T + a * np.sum(P, axis=1).T * V[:,None]
```

Comment: This might be the same as ```net_profit.T + np.einsum("i,ijk,ijk->ki", a, P, V[None,:,None])```

Comment: @Kevin Interesting solution. Note `[a]` should be used instead of `a` in this case (since `a` is a scalar).

Comment: Better yet, `np.array(a, ndmin=1, copy=False)`, or even better, just leave `a` out of the `einsum`